# passing data between java and python

Tags: java, python, django, jython

Apologies if my question is noob. I'm running Django 1.2 with pgsql 8.4 and I'm required to run a Java program after getting the inputs from the user, does some calculations and return the results back to the user.

May I know what is the best way to pass data between the Java and Python Django, such that the above scenario are taken care of? I heard of Jython, but according to the Django docs, it requires the extension jython-Django, but currently it doesn't support django 1.2.x. Should I pass the data using stdout?

thanks people for hearing me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) and run the Java program as a simple subprocess.  It's very, very simple and reasonably fast.

If you need to do something more scalable, you should look at creating a [glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net/) server with your Java code so your Python can make web services requests to the Java.  This is more scalable, but also more work.

Comment: @Lott, thanks for your suggestions. With respect to subprocess, how do i return the computed results back to Python?

Comment: @goh: The communication channels are limited only by your imagination.  Start with files.  Plain old files.  Django writes a file, your Java app reads the file and writes a new file.  You can use pipes.  You can probably search google for "Interprocess Communication" and find a half-dozen other ways two processes can communicate.  Your operating system API's include several mechanisms other than files and pipes.

Answer (score 5):

If all you are doing is calling Java for some calculations, then subprocess is the easiest way, but I just wanted to throw another option out there.

[JPype](http://jpype.sourceforge.net/) is a package that lets you run a JVM inside your Python program while calling the Java code as if it were Python ([example](http://hustleplay.wordpress.com/2010/02/18/jpype-tutorial/)).

That is, it's like Jython in that you call Java code directly and like subprocess in that you are actually running CPython. Consider JPype if for some reason the Java code is not easy to call from a shell script (aka, subprocess) or if a lot of two-way communication is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Py4J for this task:

```
from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway
gateway = JavaGateway()                        # connect to the JVM
gateway.jvm.java.lang.System.out.println('Hello World!')
```

You should first start the Java program, and then invoke Java method from Python.

py4j doesn't start jvm, it just connects to the already started Java process.

Answer (score 0):

It might be what you wanted to avoid.
but at the most simple way of things, using sockets / shared file with java will be the best solution.
python socket can send information and revise it from java.
On the other hand if that feel like a pain. if you use java and python at the same computer you can use a shared file, that java can read from and python can wright to.