# Send data from Python program to Java program

Tags: java, python, sockets, communication

I have a Python program `status.py` that prints some status updates (strings) to the console. However, I need to write a JavaFX program `Display.java` that launches the Python program and then prints the Python program's status updates to a `TextArea`.

To accomplish this I've altered `status.py` to write its status updates to a text file and then have the Java program read the text file into the `TextArea`.

The text file method is working, but I feel like there is a better way to communicate. I am thinking about having the Python program write its status updates to a socket and having the Java program listen to the socket using `ServerSocket`.

Is using a networking approach such as communicating through sockets the best way to accomplish communication between `status.py` and `Display.java`? If not, what is the best way to accomplish such inter-proccess communication?

Comment: Sockets are a perfectly reasonable means of inter-process communication, especially cross-language.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17262364/passing-data-from-a-java-program-to-a-python-program-and-getting-results-back

Comment: Thanks. I'll probably go with sockets. I have some special Python libraries that I use, and I'm not sure how that's going to work with Jython. I've never used Jython, but I will certainly take a closer look at it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options for communicating information from a Python process to a Java process:

1. Java's popular networking libraries will make it easy to read in data through a socket. Since you can easily open up a socket in Python, implementing socket communication would be the easiest solution.
2. If you have experience with [Jython](http://www.jython.org/), you can eliminate the need to perform inter-process communication by including the Python code within the Java code.