# How to connect Python chatbot and Java chat room

Tags: java, python, artificial-intelligence, chatbot

I write chatbot program using Python. When it receives a message, it computes what to say and return a message.

My friend write a chat room using Java. It is an usual chat room but when human sends message, this sends it to chatbot.

How to connect them? They run on the same PC and don't use internet.

Comment: Use this as a reference : [Send data from python to JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41406672/send-data-from-python-program-to-java-program)  , Using sockets for inter process communication [Socket](https://jj09.net/interprocess-communication-python-java/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with the runtime class. Example code:

```
public String sendMessage(String message) throws IOException {
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc = rt.exec("python /Users/user/bot.py " + message);

    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
            InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new
            InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

    // read the output from the command
    String s = null;
    StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        answer.append(s);
    }

    return answer.toString();
}
```